# Cisco Routing exclusion

Tags: routing, cisco-router

I would like to know the best way of excluding a subnet from a route without creating many routes.
For example on a switch I may have ip route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 10.54.21.1
What I would like to do is still be able to connect items going to 10.2.2.0 255.255.255.240 which are directly connected to this switch. I still want the rest of the 10.0.0.0/8 subnet to route to 10.54.21.1.

Comment: Is the interface's address belonging to the router itself (10.2.2.x) configured with a 255.255.255.240 netmask as well?

Comment: And: have you already tried and configured this, or are you asking before doing anything? Usually things already work the way you describe _by default_.

Comment: @grawity Yes there is an interface 10.2.2.0/28 configured on the switch. This interface isn't assigned to any specific port on the switch and I want the data destined for that subnet to flow through a trunk port to a hypervisor host with this interface assigned. This is in a live environment. 10.54.21.1 is the LAN port on the MPLS router attached to another switch. The traffic for 10.2.2.0/28 is flowing to MPLS as it follows the 10.0.0.0 route.

Answer (score 0):

Routers (and L3 Switches) have an internal hierarchy of which routing information is being promoted to the FIB (Forwarding Information Base, vulgo "routing table"). Cisco uses the concept of "administrative distance" (lower is better)

Sources of routing information are:

- connected routes (AD 0)
- static routes (AD 1, customizable)
- dynamic routing protocols (eBGP 20, EIGRP 90, OSPF 110, RIP 120, iBGP 200, to name a few values Cisco uses)
- if there is overlapping information avaible from multiple sources, then the source of lower AD is preferred, and gets promoted to the FIB

Since that 10.2.2.0/28 is directly attached to that routing engine, you actually cannot overwrite this "direct" or "locally attached" route (with admin distance of 0) with any static route (which can't have ad AD lower than 1).

This, however, is only true if the interface with that address/subnet (an "interface vlan xxx", I presume?) is actually in "up" state.

As long as the interface is "down", its subnet won't show up as connected route (check with `show ip route connected`) - and the traffic to that subnet will be forwarded as the routing table defines. In your case, that will be along the 10.0.0.0/8 route.